# I am trying to make Multi Level Category using laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to make Multi-Level Category using laravel but I am facing this error: How to fix this error?

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>
> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view
> not found: 1146 Table 'storykadb.category_navmenus' doesn't exist
> (SQL: select * from `category_navmenus` where `p_id` = 0)

[image]

**Model**

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class category_navmenu extends Model
{
    public function childs(){
       return $this->hasMany('App\category_navmenu','p_id');
    }
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('test',function(){
   return App\category_navmenu::with('childs')->where('p_id',0)->get();
});
```

Comment: Please rename your table `category_navmenus` from category_navmenu. It will automatically resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel Eloquent is taking the wrong table name, either you can change your Model name and table name according to Laravel's naming convention or add in the `$table` property in your model, like this :

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class category_navmenu extends Model
{
  public $table = "category_navmenu";

  public function childs(){

    return $this->hasMany('App\category_navmenu','p_id');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because Laravel will find your table by changing your classname to lowercase underscore and **plural**. Just like:
`CategoryNavmenu` will become `category_navemenus`.

You have no specifies the table name of the protected `$table`. So laravel will find the table by default rule.

You can put this line in your model:

```php
  protected $table = 'category_navemenu';
```

so laravel can find your table.

But the important thing is plz change your class name to **Upper Camel Case**。This is a normal grammatical norms.

Just Change your model file name to `CategoryNavmenu.php` and classname to `CategoryNavmenu`.